# Aligning text on diagonal path

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I have two points that draw a line when connected. The line can be both vertical horizontal, vertical, or (most commonly) diagonal.

I would like to try text along this path. I'm using C# and WinForms, but I think that isn't as important as some simple psuedo-code that may include some math (trig?) needed to find the angle of the path to align the text to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Math.Atan2() to calculate the angle.  Convert from radians to degrees by multiplying by 180 / Math.Pi.  Getting the center of rotation for RotateTransform() is the critical step to get the text aligned properly with the line.  r * Math.Cos(angle) for the X-offset from the line start point, r * Sin(angle) for the Y-offset where r is the offset from the line start point.  Adjust by the font's Height to get it above the line.

Comment: What does 'r' represent? Rotation?

Comment: I currently have ` e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(point.X, point.Y);` as the place for the start point. This seems to work without using Math.Cos/Sin, however, it is now under the line in some cases. What would you suggest I do to get it always above the line, no matter what angle I draw?

Comment: I marked this as the best answer because it covers most of what I'm looking for. I found this order-of-magnitudes easier in WPF, so I decided to do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are drawing the text in an `OnPaint()` method, you can try this ([reference](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=606627)):

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;  // your graphics object.
float deg = 45F;  // an angle, this one is 45 degrees

g.RotateTransform(deg);
g.DrawString("slopey text is fun");
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. The only problem I have currently is that it rotates all the lines and stuff I draw too- though I think I can just create a new graphics object instead.

Comment: You could probably un-rotate the text after drawing the string with `g.RotateTransform(-deg)`.

Comment: That works, thanks. I multiplied by -1, but to the same effect as you posted.